# setRightBarButtonItems iOS5 not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem

I am using the new API for UINavigationItem setRightBarButtonItems like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *buttonSettings = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] 
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                               target:self 
                                                               action:@selector(showSettings:)];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonLogout = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl target:self action:@selector(showSettings:)];


[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonLogout, buttonSettings, nil]];
```

But, only 1 button (settings) is appearing and logout button is not appearing at all. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to read `UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl` info at Apple developer reference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allowed to do it:

> UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl
>   The system page curl button. 
>   This bar button image can be used only for bar button items placed on toolbars.
>   Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
>   Declared in UIBarButtonItem.h.